# How to manipulate array in section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a single array of any count. I want to divide in different section as multiple of 7. I am unable to get this to work. Here is a sample of 2 elements.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    array =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"d",@"s",@"a",@"qq",@"dqd",@"dqq",@"qdqdf",@"dqdfqf", nil];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return ceil(array.count / 2.0); // round up the floating point division
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger sections = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];
    if (section == sections - 1) {
        NSInteger count = array.count & 2;
        if (count == 0) {
            count = 2;
        }
        return count;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    // cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @rmaddy Please help how this work

Comment: Don't completely change your question after answers are posted. It makes the answers worthless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear but I think you want 7 rows in every section except the last section which would have just enough for the last remaining rows that don't fit in the rest of the sections.

Assuming this is correct you need to properly calculate the number of sections as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return ceil(array.count / 7.0); // round up the floating point division
}
```

Now the number of rows in each section will be 7 except for the last section which could have 1 - 7.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger sections = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];
    if (section == sections - 1) {
        NSInteger count = array.count % 7;
        if (count == 0) {
            count = 7;
        }
        return count;
    } else {
        return 7;
    }
}
```

You also need to be able to convert an `indexPath` into an array index:

```
NSInteger index = indexPath.section * 7 + indexPath.row;
```

And you need to be able to convert an array index into an indexPath:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index % 7 inSection:index / 7];
```

Or, instead of all of this, you could setup your data structures to be an array of arrays. That actually makes your data better match how it will be used by the table.

Update for you revised question:

Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method needs to change:

```
//cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

to:

```
NSInteger index = indexPath.section * 7 + indexPath.row;
cell.textLabel.text = tableData[index];
```

just like I showed above.

Comment: I already told you how in the line of code I showed you after the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method.

Comment: BTW - there was a typo. Change `array.count & 7` to `array.count % 7`.

Comment: in all section first two element populate in all section.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not entirely on point with objective-C as it's been awhile.

But the easiest thing I'd think to do would be a for loop that iterates through the length of the array and at every 7th will divide the array.

Here's a bit of psuedocode.

```
for(int i =0; i<array.length<i=i+7)
{
    //take the first index, take the 7th index. 
    //split the array from the first index to the 7th
    //repeat for all remaining values.
}
```

I'm not sure if you wanted all the different sections that it could make from the 7 intervals, or only one. If you could clarify I might be able to answer this better.